# ValueError: Expected singleton: daily.attendance.line(123,124,125

Tags: odoo

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    curr = datetime.now()
    new_date = datetime.strftime(curr, '%Y-%m-%d')
    cal_obj = self.env['daily.attendance'].search([])

@api.constrains('date')
def _date_test_unique(self):
     for rec in self:
        if self.search_count([('date', '=', rec.date)]) > 1:
            raise ValidationError(_('Current Date Attendance Already Existed!'))
          
@api.onchange('user_id')
def onchange_department(self):
    if self.user_id == True:
        emps = self.env['hr.employee'].search([])
        emp_attd = []
        from datetime import datetime

        now = datetime.now() # current date and time
        check_in = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        check_in_from = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 05:30')
        check_out = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        check_out_from = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 14:30')
        for emp in emps:
            vals = {
                'employe_id':emp.id,
                'check_in': check_in_from,
                'check_out': check_out_from,
                'is_present': True
            }
            emp_attd.append([0, 0, vals])
        self.update({
            'employee_ids': emp_attd,
        })
    else:
        self.employee_ids = False
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.client',
        'tag': 'reload',
    }
```

Comment: Replace `rec` (undefined) with `self`. You need to [introduce the problem before you post any code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dear Kenly,  Thank you for ur answer and comment.... I will....! regarding your answer of replacing "self" this was  what I did before and got singleton error and to solve that I used "rec".    Of course, the singleton problem gone but now, it is requesting me to define the "rec" and this is to get a clue how to do so.   Any further support is appreciated.

Comment: Please update the question with the error log

Comment: Did you get rid of the error

Comment: No, solution so far..... I jusst updated the code and it error  as u suggest...... i get back to original error ( self not rec.)

Comment: Loop over self in `attendance_validate` before trying to access the value of `employee_ids`

Comment: Dear Kenly, Please kindly give me an example with code,  how to do it..... I am too fresh  about the loop...... even where to put these code .......etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens when Odoo tries to get `employee_ids` value from a record set but it expects a record.

```
for emp in self.employee_ids:
```

You need to loop over self then access `employee_ids` field value for each record:

***Example:***

```
def attendance_validate(self):
    for rec in self:
        for emp in rec.employee_ids:
```

You should move the following code outside the for loop

```
self.write({'state': 'validate', })
```

***Example:***

```
hr_attendance = self.env['hr.attendance']
for rec in self:
    for emp in rec.employee_ids:
        if emp.is_present == True:
            attd_crete_id = hr_attendance .create({'employee_id': emp.employe_id.id,
                                         'check_in': emp.check_in,
                                         'check_out': emp.check_out,
                                         })
    rec.write({
        'state': 'validate',
    })
    ...
```

Probably you need to call write state to validate when the `attendance_validate` method succeed (at the end)

***improvement:***

- The following expression

  ```
    if emp.is_present == True:
  ```

  can be simplified to:

  ```
    if emp.is_present:
  ```
- You are using two fields `is_present` and `is_absent`, you can simply use `is_present` and when its value is `False` (not set) the employee is absent.
- You need to remove the second if statement, which is useless

  ```
  elif emp.is_absent == True:
      if emp.is_absent == True:
  ```
- Avoid raising a validation error in the create method because it will break the workflow, instead you can define a [constraint](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.api.constrains) on `date` field:

  ```
    @api.constrains('date')
    def _date_test_unique(self):
        for rec in self:
            if self.search_count([('date', '=', rec.date)]) > 1:
                raise ValidationError(_('Current Date Attendance Already Existed!'))
  ```

***Update:***

The create method should return the newly created record:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(CLASS_NAME, self).create(vals)
    # Your code
    return res
```

Comment: I did as per your instruction and now got an other error of "The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: How did you handle the return value of `attendance_validate`?

Comment: self.write({
                        'state': 'validate',
                    })
            else:
                attd_crete_id = None
        return attd_crete_id

Comment: yes, but  i didnt be clear about ur validateion comment..... where is outside loop?                 You should move the following code outside the for loop

self.write({'state': 'validate', }) becuase if i displace it through syntax error

Comment: I added an example just after that line. The `AttributeError` mentioned above could happen if you try to get the return object ID of the attendance_validate method.

Comment: _call_kw_model_create
    return result.id if isinstance(args[0], Mapping) else result.ids
Exception

Comment: Odoo expects a record from the create method. I updated the code to use a constraint instead, try it and let me know.

Comment: Does this answer help you?

Comment: Hi Kenly, i used ur updated code and still got this error     "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'"                                                                                       
 error source "in _call_kw_model_create
    return result.id if isinstance(args[0], Mapping) else result.ids"

Comment: For ur further reference, I updated the above code ur with ur code included, if i made any missplace or the error may be from some other location other than posted here.....

Comment: Update the create method, then check if you get an error and if so try to find a line related to your code. Check my update

Comment: Did you get rid of that error?

Comment: Dear Kenly, I am really appreciate and heartly thank for all your support..... Now everything work perfectly........ You helped me alot. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

write a for loop before the if statement

```
@api.onchange('is_present')
def onchange_attendance(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.is_present:
            rec.is_absent = False
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure when you loop through the self then use loop variable

```
@api.depends('date_of_birth')
    def _compute_age(self):
        # print(self)
        for rec in self:
            # print('rec', rec.date_of_birth)
            today = date.today()
            if rec.date_of_birth:
                rec.age = today.year - rec.date_of_birth.year
            else:
                rec.age = 1
```